# Looking for Book About Druids in San Francisco

Tags: story-identification, wizards, urban-fantasy

I'm looking for a book about a druid (I think) or a wizard who has to stop the apocalypse or some end-of-the-world getup. I believe it takes place in San Francisco (or LA). To save the world, he needs to find this special woman and work with her, but it turns out that the "work" is actually intercourse. As in, they need to have intercourse to complete some ritual to prevent the end of the world. I believe the woman is also a virgin of some kind, which is why the ritual is so important. The book is fairly old (I read it about a decade ago) and I think it was based in the 80s or 90s.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details you can remember.